# babel-preset-env not transpiling arrow functions using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using babel with webpack, I'm trying to make arrow functions work with Internet Explorer, but I can't get it working.

This is my *package.json* dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

and this is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./chat.js'],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "chat.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }  
};
```

I'm using the plugins with *.babelrc*:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing something but I get the following syntax error on Internet Explorer:

```
DF.fn = () => {
        // Content
};
```

Comment: You need a polyfill for it. Core-js or babel-polyfill can do the job.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Babel 7, the behaviour of `.babelrc` [has changed](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading).

My advice is to drop `.babelrc` and put the config inside your webpack config.

Additionally you will need to either remove `exclude: /node_modules/` from your config config, or add in some conditions for not excluding any libraries that use browser incompatible code (eg, arrow functions if you want to use IE).

Personally I removed the `exclude` altogether and noticed no degredation in speed or size.

Answer (score 2):

For those using Webpack 5, you need to specify the features that you want to transpile in the `ouput.environment` configuration, as explained here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment.

I am using differential serving so I have set all the flags according to a `modern` variable (which is set to `true` only if building for recent browsers, which is the last 5 versions of Chrome and Firefox and the last 2 versions of Safari, Edge and iOS).

```js
output: {
  // ... other configs
  environment: {
    arrowFunction: modern,
    bigIntLiteral: modern,
    const: modern,
    destructuring: modern,
    dynamicImport: modern,
    forOf: modern,
    module: modern,
  },
}
```

Comment: thanks. imho this should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the target browsers for your build. Based on that `babel-preset-env` decides which transforms need to be applied. Here's [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env/) and example of config

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

And [here](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) are all possible ways to specify the browsers set.